# 2-level nested CSS selector

Tags: css, selector

I know we can do this in CSS:

```
div.className p
{
/* some style*/
}
```

But how can we do

```
div.className p span
{
/* some style */
}
```

to refer to the span in HTML like this:

```
<div class='className'>
   <p>  <span> Some text </span> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly like that. if your selector isn't working, make sure it matches your DOM tree

Comment: Quicktip: Don't unnecessarily include tag names in selectors, *i.e.*, don't use `div.className` when `.className` will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's technically nothing wrong with your selector. I would recommend not including the tag name when it isn't necessary though, as described by the [Google HTML/CSS Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Type_selectors#Type_selectors).

It's easy to get a grip on how selectors work by inspecting elements with Chrome's inspector. A full selector path is provided, like this:

[image]